# Elementor menu cart shows blank page:

Tags: wordpress, menu, cart, elementor

I'm using Elementor Pro along with a menu cart widget, and as soon as I open the sidebar of the cart, I can't see any overlay; rather, what I can see is just a blank white page.

[image]

Though it works fine, if I choose mini cart as the cart type.

[image]